# Maven POM Error : "Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.Errors"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I tried to create new POM but I got error that "Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.Errors" .
I tried restarting and checked installation of M2E. M2E has been already installed.
How can I fix the issues?

[image]

Comment: Don't include errors as screenshots. Include them (1) as text (2) in the body of your question.

Comment: First step is to. try your build on plain command line...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.